# calling youtube player api loadPlaylist returns bad request error 400

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I was trying to call method loadPlaylist in a player instance create by new YT.Player() constructor, so according to the docs

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

I can pass a param called list with the id of a playlist or an array of video ids, if I try the playlist ID all works, but if I pass an array of videos ids, got the bad request error, I have checked the request url generated by the api

http://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?action_get_list=1&style=xml&list=UOoR27IF7Jk,j67Z9D0rs5s

so the url is correct but is returning me the error, anybody know if I can't actually pass videos IDS and the docs are incorrect? and if so how can I create a playlist from the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the solution, not the reason, the api has two ways of calling the loadPlaylist method, one is by passing an object with the params and other passing the args directly, for some reason the passing the args inside an object way don't work if I'm passing the videos IDs, but if I use the other way (passing directly the args) works properly, mmmm, I wonder if this is still a bug, anyways hope this help somebody else

Comment: The object syntax requires an optional parameter called `listType`. Did you specify that?

Answer (score 0):

change the 'list' in the playerVars to 'playlist' and it instantly works!

```
if (this.listType) {
                playerConfig.playerVars.listType=this.listType;
                playerConfig.playerVars.playlist=this.playlist;
            }
```