# About Use YouTube Player API loadPlaylist

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-api

How do I use the `loadPlaylist` option so that the next video is played automatically?
My code is like this, but it won't work, can't play video:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      loadPlaylist:{
        listType:'playlist',
        list:['4Ivdp8kj_0U','4MJRS-cLozU'],
        index:parseInt(0),
        suggestedQuality:'small'
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
     // setTimeout(stopVideo, 60000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

I want to achieve the effect of this example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DdCoNbbRvQ&list=RD02_VTY8ftr1vY

Thanks very much.

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean? Could you put this in a jsfiddle along with your HTML? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 5):

I was running into this issue yesterday actually. First of all, in your `onPlayerReady` function, you need to be calling `loadPlaylist` since that will cue up the playlist and start playing it.

However, the issue I was running into is that using the object syntax when calling an playlist made up of an array of video ids, I would get an error. After some Googling, I found this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866377/calling-youtube-player-api-loadplaylist-returs-bad-request-error-400) that suggested using the argument syntax and that seemed to fix it. See differences here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playlist_Queueing_Functions

I took your code and changed the `onPlayerReady` to use the `loadPlaylist` function with the argument syntax and it now works. See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rustybailey/9kFyx/

Answer (score 0):

`index:parseInt(0)` – this parameter isn't required:
by default index in list is 0